# Сложные JOIN запросы MySQL PHP

Tags: php, join, codeigniter, sql, mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть две таблицы:

Posts :

```
|  id  |  game_id  |   date     |  title |
|  1   |  7        | 2014-07-10 |  str_1 |
|  2   |  8        | 2014-07-10 |  str_2 |
```

Tasks :

```
|  id  |  name     |  game_id  |  date      |
|   1  | string_1  |  7        | 2014-07-10
|   2  | string_2  |  7        | 2014-07-10 |
```

Мне нужно выбрать `posts.game_id = 7`, и получить записи в массиве.

В результате должен получиться массив с одной записью из Posts, 
содержащий в себе массив из двух записей из таблицы Tasks, как-то так, надеюсь доступно объяснил.

Сейчас пробую делать так:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('tasks');
$this->db->join('posts','tasks.game_id = posts.game_id','left');
$query = $this->db->where('posts.game_id',$game)->get()->result_array();
return $query;
```

Но в итоге получаю массив из 3 элементов, ещё и с повторяющимися значениями.

Я конечно могу сначала получить одну таблицу, а потом в цикле прогнать её, получив для каждой записи массив из второй таблицы, но так я никогда не пойму суть JOIN, хотя уже перечитал пол Хабра, для новичков мало понятно. И интересно какой из способов будет более производительный, с JOIN, или мой вариант с циклом, при условии что в таблице будет больше 100 записей, и 500 юзеров в сутки.

Comment: Замените left (в join'е) на right. у вас не в ту сторону соединение идет.

Answer (score 1):

А чтобы убрать повторяющиеся значения можно (нужно) использовать Distinct:

```
...
$this->db->select('DISTINCT *')->from('tasks');
...
```